# How do :default => 0 and :null => false differ for integer fields in migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null, migration, default

If I use a migration to update a database, and I add an integer field like this:

```
t.integer :foo :default => 0, :null => false
```

What is the default state of existing and new records in the database?  I hoping the answer is:
- Both will read back foo as 0.

Is default => 0 necessary, if I have :null => false?

Just trying to understand the difference between the two...

Comment: it's dependent to your Database. Not Rails.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`:null => false` tells your database not to accept `NULL` values.

`:default => 0` does two things:

1. Tell your database to use '0' as the default value when `NULL` or nothing is specified in a query.
2. Tell rails to use '0' as a default value when creating a new object.

Point 2 makes sure that when you save your new object, you actually have a valid value in place.

To answer your question: If you don't want `NULL` values in your database, set `:null => false`, otherwise just use the `:default` parameter. Mind you, '0' and `NULL` are not the same things.

Not having `NULL` values might be important for indexing purposes or if you need to provide direct database access to a third party.

Comment: <Tell your database to use '0' as the default value when NULL or nothing is specified in a query.>  By this, do you mean that it will read back as 0 if I have an existing database record before the migration?  So if I do Table.value, on an old record, value will == 0?

Comment: Yes. If you have a table column that contains `NULL` values, but you set a default, then that default will be returned.

Comment: This is the enlightening, valuable info:

"Not having NULL values might be important for indexing purposes or if you need to provide direct database access to a third party."

Comment: @ahnbizcad don't understand this, how is direct connection for a 3rd party related to not wanting null values?