# rails add_column with default value but the default value don't take effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My rails version is 3.2.8 and use the default  database.
This is my migration code:

```
class AddQuantityToLineItem < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :line_items, :quantity, :integer,:default=>1
  end
end
```

[I find a explaination about :default option here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012871/how-do-default-0-and-null-false-differ-for-integer-fields-in-migrations) and as it said,when i create a
new LineItem ,it should have a default quantity=1,but here is what i get from rails console:

```
lineb=LineItem.new
#<LineItem id: nil, product_id: nil, cart_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, quantity: nil>
```

> And when i get LineItem from the database,the quantity field is nil
>   too.

And here is the db/schema.rb :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121008065102) do

  create_table "carts", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "line_items", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "quantity"
  end

  create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price",       :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                :null => false
  end

end
```

Comment: rollback the migration and rerun again.

Comment: i had a similar problem. I had two "change_column" statements in a migration and the second wasn't have any effect on the schema., What worked for me was splitting my two "change_column" statements into two migrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your migration should work fine. Based on your schema though it looks like it hasn't actually taken effect, since `t.integer "quantity"` has no default value.

The line in the schema for `quantity` should look like this:

```
t.integer  "quantity",   :default => 1
```

Make sure you have actually run your migration (`bundle exec rake db:migrate`), and if that doesn't work then rollback (`bundle exec rake db:rollback`) and run the migration again (as @surase.prasad suggested).