# Null constraint error while Default value is set Ruby On Rails - Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

In my database i have a table with schema like below

```
  create_table "external_source", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "external_id"
    t.string   "permalink",                             null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
    t.boolean  "is_deleted",         default: false,    null: false
    t.string   "company_name",       default: ""
    t.boolean  "hide_salary",        default: true,     null: false
  end
```

But when i tried to insert values without `is_deleted` parameter, `Rails` server throws null constraint violation error like:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null
>   value in column "is_deleted" violates not-null constraint

Now when I have set its default value I am not expecting this error. can you tell me what wrong am I doing. Thank You

here is the JSON to insert

```
{
  "data":
  [
    {
      "external_id":"2262a0228sf-1b9e-sd4e76-b5d7-a8ba01783ebb9i3413139",
      "permalink": '234242341',
      "hide": true,
      "company_name": "com1",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that does the create statement.

Comment: @Anton i updated with json

Comment: Great! Please add the controller code as well.

Answer (score 2):

***null*** and ***default*** have different purposes in the migration. If you want the default value to be set as false, when no value is set in the controller just use,

**default: false**,

there is no need to use the **null:false** parameter in your case. **default** would do the work for you. For more explanation of null and default please check the following link  [How do :default => 0 and :null => false differ for integer fields in migrations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012871/how-do-default-0-and-null-false-differ-for-integer-fields-in-migrations)

Comment: i was doing this thing before which didn't worked so i added `null: false` which also didn't work

Comment: Can you please add the controller code used for creation.

Comment: What does ExternalSource.new display in rails console?

Comment: sorry for late reply. internet is really bad. yeah that shows the default values. i check.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the controller code. Remove the null: false from the migration file and check the code in controller.

Comment: that answer you link seems to rely on mysql brokenness,.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a validation in model, sth like `validates :is_deleted, presence: true?` if so:

- get rid of this validation, or
- keep validation and set as false by default (if missing), i.e.

  ```
  def default_deleted_status
    self.status ||= false
  end
  ```